# getting error while starting airflow scheduler - cannot import name 'BaseKeyValueStoreBackend' from 'celery.backends.base'

Tags: celery, airflow

I have installed airflow on windows 10 by enabling Windows Subsystem for Linux option.
Airflow is configured for celery executor.
Aiflow webserver is starting without error but when I try to start airflow scheduler it is giving error

> "File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/airflow/executors/celery_executor.py", line 38, in ?
> from celery.backends.base import BaseKeyValueStoreBackend
> ImportError: cannot import name 'BaseKeyValueStoreBackend' from 'celery.backends.base' >(/home/airflowadmin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py)"

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting in the airflow configuration that controls the celery backend.  You can configure this using the [`AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND` setting](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#result-backend).   If you are using redis as the backend, the process is straightforward, just use the next database up from your broker as the backend database and you're good to go.